# Stop a Mediaplayer that was started from another application

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

How do applications like Soundcloud stop another app's `MediaPlayer`? For example, when I am playing a song through Google Music and I open SoundCloud, the song from Google Music stops playing as soon as the Soundcloud song starts. I might be missing something obvious but I have always wondered how this is achieved.

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  Audio Focus.  See [Request the Audio Focus](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html#RequestFocus)

```
AudioManager am = mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
...

// Request audio focus for playback
int result = am.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener,
                                 // Use the music stream.
                                 AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                                 // Request permanent focus.
                                 AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
    am.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver);
    // Start playback.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @TCA's answer:

There is only one AudioManager. So, Audio focus is assigned to each application that requests it **one by one**. **This means that if another application requests audio focus, your application will lose it**. You will be notified of the loss of audio focus through the onAudioFocusChange handler of the Audio Focus Change Listener (**afChangeListener in TCA's answer**) you registered when requesting the audio focus.

```
private OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener =
      new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
              public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                         AudioManager am =(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                switch (focusChange) {

                       case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) :
                       //Transient audio loss
                       break;

                       case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) :
                       //Audio focus loss. Stop playback.
                       break;

                       case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) :
                       //Audio focus gain. Start playback.
                       break;
                       default: break;
}
}
};
```